# Find word with most matching letters

Tags: python

I have 2 lists:

```
l1 = ['UK', 'GER', 'POL']
```

and

```
l2 = ['Germany', 'Poland', 'United Kingdom']
```

The lists are referring to countries but don't match in order.

Is there a way to match the values in `l1` to `l2` based on the number of letters in `l2`?

So the output is :

```
dic = {'UK': 'United Kingdom',
       'GER': 'Germany',
       'POL': 'Poland'}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the `.__setitem__` function?

Comment: I'm not familiar. I'll have a look. thanks

Comment: One very simple but possibly not sufficient way would be to simply use regex and pattern matching. But you if you want to match exactly (not most or at least) one item from list to the other any possible also not the same item to two, you might want to use restricting rules and a ranking

Comment: I don't think most matching letters is going to work. What would you do with "UK" -> "United Kingdom" and "Ukraine" or "SL" -> "Saint Lucia" and "Sierra Leone"? If you know both lists a priori, it might make sense to just define the mapping without guessing.

Comment: ah yes that would be a problem. I might be alright though as there are a select number of  countries. but good point

Answer (score 1):

Something like this may work for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

l1 = ['UK', 'GER', 'POL']
l2 = ['Germany', 'Poland', 'United Kingdom', 'Ukraine']

d = {}
for short in l1:
    lower = short.lower()

    # Match prefix or initials.
    matches = [x for x in l2 if
               x.lower().startswith(lower) or
               ''.join(w[0] for w in x.split()).lower() == lower]

    if len(matches) == 0:
        print('no match', short)
    elif len(matches) > 1:
        print('ambiguous', short, matches)
    else:
        d[short] = matches[0]

print(d)
```

```
$ ./test.py 
ambiguous UK ['United Kingdom', 'Ukraine']
{'GER': 'Germany', 'POL': 'Poland'}
```

I added "Ukraine" to test handling ambiguous matches.